# Pyspark throwing error as ': No suitable driver' for Oracle

Tags: pyspark

I'm new to Pyspark and trying to establish a **Pyspark connection to Oracle** with the below code
. I have added the ojdbc.jar path:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Spark_Oracle_Connection').getOrCreate()
os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = r"C:\Users\name\Downloads\ojdbc8.jar"

driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
url='jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<servicename>'
username = 'user'
pwd = 'pwd'
query='SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE'
df = (spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", driver)
    .option("url", url)
    .option("dbtable", query)
    .option("user", username)
    .option("password", pwd)
    .load()
)
```

but I get the below **error**:

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.load.
    : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```